# Regex para pegar palavras com letra maiúscula no meio de uma frase

Tags: javascript, regex

minha necessidade é pegar palavras que comecem com letras maiúsculas no meio de uma frase.

Exemplo: "O Facebook e Twitter são interessantes. Você pode fazer cadastro a qualquer hora".

No exemplo acima, preciso pegar Facebook e Twitter, mas não "Voce".

Minha ideia seria pegar todas as palavras com letra maiúscula em que antes não tenha um ponto e um espaço em sequência. Já tentei algumas coisas, mas nada da certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é usar *Negative Lookbehind*. Assim, sua regex ficaria assim:

```js
'(?<!\.\s)[A-Z][a-z]+'
```

Código completo:

```js
const regexp = /(?<!\.\s)[A-Z][a-z]+/g
const text = "O Facebook e Twitter são interessantes. Você pode fazer cadastro a qualquer hora"

const result_array = text.match(regexp)
console.log(result_array)
```

**O que são lookbehinds**

lookbehinds são casos especifícos de lookarounds. Aqui a definição do [livro](https://www.amazon.com.br/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Understand-Productive-ebook/dp/B007I8S1X0/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=jeffrey%20friedl&qid=1606877484&sr=8-1) do Jeffrey Friedl:

> lookaround são semelhantes aos metacaracteres de limite de palavra como \b ou as âncoras ^ e $ no sentido de que não correspondem ao texto, mas sim a posições com o texto. No entanto, lookaround é um construto muito mais geral do que o limite e âncoras de palavra de caso especial

> Um tipo de lookaround, denominado lookahead, procura adiante no texto (em direção à direita) para ver se sua subexpressão pode corresponder e é bem-sucedida como um componente regex. O lookahead positivo é especificado com a sequência especial! (?=...), como em (?=\d), que é bem-sucedido nas posições em que o dígito vem a seguir. Outro tipo de lookaround é o **lookbehind**, que olha para trás (para a esquerda). É dado com a sequência especial (?<=...), como em (?<=\d)", que é em posições bem-sucedidas com um dígito à esquerda (ou seja, nas posições após um dígito). (Tradução Livre)

Apenas complementando, `(?<=...)` é o *Positive Lookbehind*, enquanto no seu caso usamos `(?<!...)` que é o *Negative Lookbehind*. Recomendo a leitura dessa seção do livro para maiores esclarecimentos. (Ver paǵinas 59-67).

Comment: Pois é. Dessa forma pega, mas não poderia alterar a string original, tirando os espaços. Talvez eu não tenha me explicado bem. O que to tentando fazer é identificar essas palavras, pra depois colocar um "#" antes de cada uma. É pra um bot do Twitter. Mas a partir da tua ideia já da pra ter uma noção!

Comment: Certo @MarcioSouza . Editei a resposta para fazer o regex na string direto.

Comment: Valeu @Lucas, deu certo. Não sabia do conceito de Lookaround. Muito interessante.

Comment: Complementando a solução com adição das hashtags:
`const regexp = /(?<!\.\s)[A-Z][a-z]+/g
const text = "O Facebook e Twitter são interessantes. Você pode fazer cadastro a qualquer hora"

const result_array = text.match(regexp)

result_array.forEach((word)=>{
    text = text1.replace(word, `#${word}`)
});`